# Adjust mouse cursor speed independently of scroll wheel speed

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mouse-wheel, mouse-cursor

In Windows 8.1, there is *one* slider (hooray for simplicity) that adjusts both how many lines to scroll when using the scroll wheel, but also the mouse cursor speed.

How do I adjust the two independently? (I need a fast mouse cursor and slow scrolling.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the traditional control panel, right click in the very bottom left (where the Windows flag is).  The old Mouse control panel will be in there with the two separate controls for mouse speed and scroll lines.